# Replacing HTML content with dojo and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dojo

**Have made a table and stored it in a variale getcontent by using basic HTML.**

```
getcontent="<table style="height: 1000px; ; width: 500px;" border="1">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>[Assignment name]</td>
    <td>[<span>Approximate Value of Contract</span>]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>"
```

**Contentinsquare is an array containg string which can be filled in th table. (SQUARE BRACKETS] in getcontent**

contentinsquare=["name","100$"]

**i want the value of contentinsqaure to be placed in between the sqaure brackets.For that i have used the code  :-**

```
 var contentinsquare=["name","100$"]
  var  strInputCode = contentinsquare[1].replace(/&(lt|gt);/g, function (strMatch, p1){
                return (p1 == "lt")? "<" : ">";
            });
            var strTagStrippedText = strInputCode.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");

    contentinsquare[1]=strTagStrippedText


var strforlabelname = []
    var strfortextarea = []
    var strfortext = []
    var str = []
    label = dojo.query('label');
    console.log(label, "all label names")
    for( i = 0; i < label.length; i++)
    {
        if(label[i].id != "")
        {
            inner = dojo.byId(label[i].id).innerHTML
            var name = inner.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');
            strforlabelname.push(name)
        }
    }
    console.log(strforlabelname, "string")
    text = dojo.query('input')
    for( i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
    {
        if(text[i].id == "")
        {

        }
        else
        {
            innertext = dijit.byId(text[i].id).getValue();

            str.push(innertext)
//console.log(str,"strng1")
        }
    }
    textarea = dojo.query('textarea')
    for( i = 0; i < textarea.length; i++)
    {
        if(textarea[i].id == ""||textarea[i].id =="textareaidfirst")
        {

        }
        else
        {
            innertextarea = dojo.byId(textarea[i].id).value
            str.push(innertextarea)

        }
        }
for( i = 0; i < strforlabelname.length; i++)
        {
    for( j = 0; j < contentinsquare.length; j++)
    {

            if(contentinsquare[j] == strforlabelname[i])
            {
                var patt = new RegExp("\\[" + strforlabelname[i] + "\\]", "g")
                getcontent = getcontent.replace(patt, str[i]);



            }

        }

}

This results to :-
```

***Result :-***

```
"<table style="height: 1000px; ; width: 500px;" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>name</td>
<td>[<span>Approximate Value of Contract</span>]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>"
```

that is the sqaure brackets contaning `<span>` tag is not working. i want the 100 $ to be replaced over thr.

Comment: Try adding a bit more explanation to your question. At the present it looks more like a copy paste set of code.

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. Maybe if you put the text and question at the top and then add your example code after the actual question?

Comment: I have edited it, I hope it helps

Comment: Start over - write the question out as clearly as possible in English, then add in the minimal amount of code to illustrate.